# files organization in objective c

Tags: objective-c, resources, organization

i've done a project with about 40-50 classes and i want to make order, what is the best practices to divide file .h, .m, .xib and resources files in folder in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I usually divide them into groups based on function.

As a first cut, you might start by dividing according to the model/view/controller split.